# How to donate money to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to donate money to Stack Overflow? Don't get me wrong... I'm not rich, but this website has helped me so many times that a bit of come back would be great!

```
if ('happy'){
    return donate;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackexchange.com/about (scroll to the bottom).  I think they're doing OK....

Comment: You could always buy ad space and just fill it with blank space.

Comment: @JoshC Those are all still non-monetary donations.

Comment: I like a comment an user did in the other post:Everything else, they can buy. But what each of us does every day for free is what gives the site its value. Keep doing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally, I think the best way to give back is through your time.

- Answer questions.
- Ask good questions that will help others.
- Make edits, improve content, help moderate

Unless they're trying to raise a VC round and you're an accredited investor, I doubt they're interested in your money.

Comment: You may be in the habit of turning down free money offered to you with no strings attached, but I'm not, and I don't know why SE would be.

Comment: @Servy I'm neither an accountant nor a tax lawyer, but I suspect that small-scale donations would just be painful for us to manage. The offer of cash donations is appreciated, but we'd much rather folks contributed to the sites in the ways Mike described here.

Comment: Considering that SE is making money out of their sites, actively contributing to the SO community is indeed an indirect way of donating them money.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella *"(...)SE is making money out of their sites"* OK, but __how__? Don't try to make me believe they can cover all their insanely high server hosting and staff costs *just* by getting their ads placed here. (Hardly any big site can, so this is why some can't do without a fundraising campaign from time to time.) I've looked around, but I've never seen that question answered in full detail anywhere. Or I've missed it.